# Corrupt PDFs after taking them from FTP server

Tags: python, pdf, ftp

I need to take PDF files from a clients ftp, move them onto my pc, move their uploaded files to a folder called 'transferred' and delete them from the previous directory.
my code is

```
ftp.cwd('/folder1/')
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
os.chdir('path')
datestr = time.strftime("%d-%m")
os.chdir(datestr)
os.chdir('Folder1')

filenames = ftp.nlst()
print(filenames)

for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        local_filename = os.path.join(newdir, filename)
        file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
        remotefile = open(filename, 'rb')
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + 'transferred/' + filename, remotefile)


        file.close()
        ftp.delete(filename)
```

when i do this, it copies the files over to my pc, moves them to the transferred folder. all fine. however, the PDFs are then corrupt on my pc and on the FTP server... why is this? is my code wrong?

Comment: You have to make sure that the transfer is BINARY. …the primary reason for PDFs getting corrupted with FTP-transfers is that they are treated as text documents with changing of line endings etc.

Comment: ok @MaxWyss i get that. is my code wrong? i thought i was transferring them as binary. i use storbinary, retrbinary, 'rb' and 'wb'.